# Can I use the word "library" to refer to collections of things other than books or software?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

It makes sense to say "library of books".  Is it legitimate to use the word "library" in other contexts.

For example, could one have a "library of hedgehogs" or a "library of apples"?

Comment: The collective noun for hedgehogs is either "nest" or "array", according to http://christchurchcitylibraries.com/kids/animals/groups/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. A place set apart to contain books, periodicals, and other material
>      for reading, viewing, listening, study, or reference, as a room, set
>      of rooms, or building where books may be read or borrowed.
> 2. A collection of any materials for study and enjoyment

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/library

The word library is often used for categorical collections. It could be a collection of refrence materials. Books or other forms of media like audio cd's, DVD's and magazines are forms of reference and entertainment. You could simply say you have a 'collection of hedgehogs' or use a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/Collection) to find synonyms.

Answer (score 6):

I think a library implies that the objects are labeled or organized in some fashion, or used as a reference. So perhaps if you had a museum of stuffed hedgehogs from different time periods you could refer to it as a library of hedgehogs.

Comment: I like it: **In his back yard, he planted a library of roses.**