# What does a library mean other than a place for a collection of books?

Tags: meaning

Does the word "library" mean other than a place for a collection of books as in the following sentence?

> Instead of purchasing what they need like a normal customer,
>   wardrobers turn retail stores into their own private libraries.

Answer (score 4):

In your sentence, they are saying that *"wardrobers"* treat the retail stores as they would a library. When you go to a library, you do not purchase a book, you simply borrow it for a bit, and then return it when you are done with it. Similarly, the *wardrobers* mentioned "borrow" clothing from the retail stores by purchasing them, and then returning the clothing again to the stores after they are finished.

*This leads me to believe that the article is talking about people who regularly purchase clothing, leave the tags on, use them, and then return the clothing for a refund after they have worn them.*

Comment: The OP's question is What does *library* mean in this context, the same as usual or something different, i.e., whether the word has other meanings.

Comment: Also, *borrow* is certainly not the word. They don't agree that they "borrow" as such, they either "buy" or take it on "trial" and then quietly return the next day with not so much as a comment. :)

Comment: @Kris Valid points, I tweaked the answer's wording based on your input. Is that better?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of **[library](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/library)** in M-W is most illuminating:

> a place in which literary, musical, artistic, or reference materials (as books, manuscripts, recordings, or films) are kept ***for use but not for sale*** [emphasis added]

In sharp contrast, **[retail store](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/retail-store)** means

> (business) a shop which ***sells*** goods to individual customers

Retail stores intend to *sell* goods. They do not intend to *lend* goods for no fee. According to the quote, wardrobers are subverting the very purpose of retail stores and treating them like *lending libraries*.

Answer (score 1):

The word *library* here means exactly as given in the dictionary.

However, the key word here is *turn*.

The sentence is literary and requires the reader to go metaphorical in understanding it.

The expression *turn* here is used to suggest 'convert' i.e., 'treat it as if it were'. As such, the idea is to suggest that people behave just as they would in their personal library -- pick up what suits the moment, use it, and replace it like nothing happened. They do not bother to purchase.

The trend among some of the fashion-conscious people who cannot afford to, or do not like to, spend big money on clothes and accessories, is that they are increasingly picking up trendy items from stores, using them for the evening and merrily returning them the next day.

Comment: I think "do not bother to purchase" somewhat overstates the case. Presumably they *do* in fact "purchase" the items (how many retail stores would allow potential customers to take *clothing* home "on approval"?) The "library borrowing" implication comes from the fact that they bring the item back and get a refund soon afterwards.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In that case, the argument would not have arisen in the first place, right? The author's point is the customer's intention -- to use it and return it, not to own it.

Comment: Not sure I follow that. Are you saying *no money changes hands?* As I said, that seems vanishingly unlikely. I read OP's citation as saying they don't *purchase in the normal way* - that's to say the normal way is to buy things that you keep. The "library user" way is to treat the price as a "refundable deposit" - they still have to purchase the clothes in order to be allowed to take them home and wear them. It's just that they know perfectly well *at time of purchase* that they'll be bringing them back soon for a refund.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *It's just that ... back soon for a refund.* -- precisely.

Answer (score -2):

In this sentence the word library refers to a collection of objects/material which are systematically arranged.

Comment: Is it commonly used to refer to a collection of things other than books?

Comment: No, the word *"library"* here refers to a collection of things you can borrow.

Comment: Ordinarily, you are correct, [library can be used for a collection of items](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38907/5438). However, as @PeterShor mentioned, that's not how it's being used in the sentence.

Comment: Those poor retail stores also have "a collection of objects/material which are systematically arranged" -- but for sale, not lending.